# Why can't I find my file when using a function from a file inside a different folder?

Tags: ruby

So my project hierarchy is as follows:

```
.
└── project
    ├── main.rb
    ├── res
    │   └── test.txt
    └── modules
        └── printer.rb
```

My printer file looks like this containing one function which prints the contents of a text file into the console:

```
def print_file_dir(file)
  logo = File.open(__dir__ + file, 'r');
  logo.each_line do |line|
    puts line
  end
  logo.close
  puts
end
```

And I call my method like this:

```
require_relative 'modules/printer'
print_file_dir('/res/logo.txt')
```

However, when I call my `print_file_dir` method on `test.txt` in my `res` folder it throws the following error:

> .../modules/printer.rb:3:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - .../modules/res/test.txt (Errno::ENOENT)

How can I stop it from getting files from the modules folder where the `printer.rb` file is located and instead from where I state the file relative to the initial directory?

Comment: How do you call your method and how do you specify your file name when you call your method?

Comment: @RoanFourie edited OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change your code in your module to the code below, you will get the desired result:

```
    def print_file_dir(file)
        logo = File.open(Dir.getwd + file, 'r');
        logo.each_line do |line|
            puts line
        end
        logo.close
        puts
    end
```

Comment: It's really odd because when i use `Dir.getwd` it tries to locate another directory in my system. That's really odd?

Comment: Wait nevermind, I'm using atom and its a bug with the ruby builder and having multiple project folders

Comment: O okay, cool. You almost had me their for a moment. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the file path logic from the method: (I've refactored the method a little bit)

```
# project/modules/printer.rb

def print_file(filename)
  IO.foreach(filename) { |line| puts line }
  puts
end
```

And instead pass the filename relative to the caller:

```
# project/main.rb

require_relative 'modules/printer'
print_file 'res/logo.txt'
```

or an absolute filename:

```
print_file '/path/to/project/res/logo.txt'
```

which could also be retrieved via [`__dir__`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-__dir__):

```
print_file File.join(__dir__, 'res', 'logo.txt')
```